# How to replace the value between multiple tags of same name of string type in java

Tags: java

```
String xml ="<country>US</country><country>INDIA</country>";
```

How to replace the value between the country tags in this case as both the tags are of same name

The code changes i did 
as

```
            int startPos =  xml.indexOf("<country>") + "<country>".length();
            int endPos =  xml.indexOf("</country>", startPos);
            String stry1= "UK";

            xml = xml.substring(0, startPos)+stry1+xml.substring(endPos, xml.length());
            System.out.println("xml 1st time is:"+ xml);
```

Comment: I was able to replace the value of the 1st tag by doing this  xml.substring(0, startPos)+stry1+xmlDoc1.substring(endPos, xml.length()); where Stry1 = "UK"

Comment: how you did can you share ? also what is your expected result?

Comment: Put your code in the question please.

Comment: I have updated the code changes it only updated the 1st country tag value from US to UK , but for the 2nd one it couldn't update

Comment: @SambeetDas: You want to replace it with what? Include a sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly but if you want to replace all countries with UK it works like this:

```
    String xml = "<country>US</country><country>INDIA</country>";
    String replaceBy = "UK";
    System.out.println(xml.replaceAll("<country>.*?</country>", "<country>" + replaceBy + "</country>"));
```

I used a non-greedy regex to match all country tags and replace them by country-tags with UK in between.

UPDATE:

If you have a map and you want to replace specific countries with other countries:

```
    Map<String, String> countryMap = new HashMap<>();
    countryMap.put("US", "UK");
    countryMap.put("INDIA", "RSA");

    String xml = "<country>US</country><country>INDIA</country>";

    for (Entry<String, String> entry : countryMap.entrySet()) {
        xml = xml.replace("<country>" + entry.getKey() + "</country>", "<country>" + entry.getValue() + "</country>");
    }

    System.out.println(xml);
```

If you have a list of countries and you want to replace the countries in the xml with the ones in your list:

```
    List<String> countries = Arrays.asList("UK", "RSA");

    String xml = "<country>US</country><country>INDIA</country>";

    xml = xml.replaceAll("<country>.*</country>", countries .stream()
                                                            .map(c -> "<country>" + c + "</country>")
                                                            .collect(Collectors.joining()));

    System.out.println(xml);
```

Comment: hi if want to replace the tags with different values how can i do that <country>UK</country> and <country>RSA</country>

Comment: Do you know which country is replaced by which other country?